Repair Windows 10 boot directly from installation folder
Does anyone know if it's possible to repair the Windows 10 boot directly from the installation folder by accessing the SSD from another computer or phone?

Phone? I must be missing something.

@DavidAnderson With Android phones, at least, you could put a drive in a USB tray, connect that to a phone, and navigate the files on the drive.

Are you asking whether it is possible, or HOW to do this? What is the nature of the boot's current brokenness? What have you tried? Windows 10 has built-in repair functions, and repair functions on OS install disks. It may be possible to remove the drive from this computer and add it as removable storage on a different device (computer or capable phone) and modify files as well. But your question needs more specificity and detail. Please add that.
